# Getting error of "cannot get" while making an api in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, npm

I am working on to make REST API in express js but getting an error "Cannot GET /api/bears".
here is my code

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose   = require('mongoose');
var Bear = require('./app/models/bear');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/api', { useNewUrlParser: true }); // connect to our database




app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 //routes for api
 var router = express.Router();


router.use(function(req, res, next) {

    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next();
});

 router.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.json({message: "Welcome to my Api"});
 });

 router.route('/bears')

    .post(function(req,res){
        var bear = new Bear();
        bear.name = req.body.name;


        bear.save(function(err){
            if(err)
            {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message: 'bear created!'});
        });
    });

 app.use('/api', router);

 app.listen(port);
 console.log("Magic happens on port" + port);
```

app/models/bear.js

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var BearSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Bear', BearSchema);
```

On localhost:3000/api, everything works fine but on localhost:3000/api/bears I am getting **Cannot GET /api/bears**

Could anyone help me where I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will certainly get this error

> Cannot GET /api/bears

The second word is important here : `GET`

You defined your route with :

```
router.route('/bears').post(function(req,res){ [...] })
```

If you send a GET request, you will certainly not match a route. Make a POST request instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have created route with POST method to create bear but don't have route for getting the data:

```
router.route('/bears').post(function.....
```

That's why you are getting:

> 400 Cannot GET /api/bears

Add something like this and try again.

```
router.route('/bears').get(function (req, res) {
    Bear.find({}, function (err, result) {
        res.status(200).send({ result });
    })
});
```